# How should I obtain the `ModeR/M` byte corresponding to a `call dword ptr` instruction in x86, using Intel's docs?

Tags: assembly, encoding, x86, intel, machine-code

I debugged the following code in VS2017 (notice the breakpoint below):

[image]

Following you'll find the disassembly for the breakpoint alluded above:

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, the machine code generated by the compiler for the instruction `call dword ptr [fp]` was `FF 55 F8` where the `FF`is the opcode for the call instruction, `55` is the value for the `ModeR/M` byte and `F8` is an 8-bit displacement with value -8, which I will explain below.

Now, if you look at the "Table 2-2: 32 bit addressing forms with the ModeR/M" byte below, obtained from Volume 2A of Intel's "64 IA-32 architectures software developer manual", you'll notice that I highlighted the number 55 mentioned above which corresponds to an effective address `[EBP]+disp8`. That is, the `CALL` instruction in the assembler will jump to the instruction whose address is obtained from the address in the register EBP plus the 8-bit displacement mentioned above with value -8. And this address is correct. It corresponds to the address of a JMP instruction which finally transfers the code to the function `f`.

[image]

Thus everything looks fine. But there is one important point that I'm missing: I should have obtained the `ModeR/M` byte using the CALL instruction reference in the Intel's manual and the Table 2.2 shown above. But I still have no idea how to do this. Any hint will be highly appreciated, as I have been working on this for several days already, and I'm still clueless about this.

Comment: See also [How to read the Intel Opcode notation](//stackoverflow.com/a/53976236) for the same detail Ross explained about the `/2` part of the modrm specified by `call`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're missing is that part of the opcode is encoded in the ModR/M byte.  Normally the ModR/M byte encodes two operands.  The first operand is a register or memory operand as given in the row labels on the left of the table, while the second operand is a register given by the column headings at the top of the table.  For instructions with only one operand, like the CALL instruction, the second operand is instead used to provide additional opcode bits.

If you look at the documentation for the CALL instruction you'll see that opcode for a "Call near, absolute indirect, address given in r/m32" instruction is listed as `FF /2`. The `/2` indicates that the additional opcode bits in the ModR/M byte have the value 2 in this instruction.  If you then look across the "(in decimal) /digit (Opcode)" column headings you'll see that the number 2 appears at the head of a column.  If you look down that column you'll see `55` on the row labelled "[EBP] + disp8".

This is documented in the Intel Software Developers Manual Volume 2 in section 3.1.1.1 Opcode Column in the Instruction Summary Table (Instructions without VEX prefix):

> - /digit — A digit between 0 and 7 indicates that the ModR/M byte of the instruction uses only the r/m (register
>     or memory) operand. The reg field contains the digit that provides an extension to the instruction's opcode.

---

The only other thing you're missing is that `call dword ptr [fp]` is text generated by the disassembler.  It was never assembled and how would be assembled depends on how `fp` is defined.  The disassembler knows from the debug information that the compiler generated where the local variable `fp` lives on the stack, and knows that `[ebp - 8]` can be used to access it.  It displayed `fp` instead of `[ebp - 8]` because the former would be more meaningful in most cases. You should be able to see later by unchecking "Show symbol names".

Note that the `call std::operator<<std:char_traits<char> >` line can't be assembled regardless how `std`, `operator`, etc. are defined, and so shows that the disassembly you're looking at is not actually meant to be assembled.  This is often the case with disassemblers.  The output is meant to be informative, a better alternative than looking at a sequence of hexadecimal bytes.  It's not meant to be a reversible process.

Comment: But I'm assuming that I don't know about the `ByteR/M` = 55. That is, the column with number 2 at the top is still not enough to identify the effective address `[EBP]+ disp8`.

Comment: @Alexander From where are you starting? If you know opcode byte is `FF` and the ModR/M byte is `55`, as you know from your disassembly, then you know the effective address is "[EBP] + disp8". If you know the instruction is a CALL with a "near, absoulte indirect" operand and that the effective address is "[EBP] + disp8" then you know that opcode byte is `FF` and the ModR/M byte is `55`.  The compiler knew this  when it emitted these bytes in the code it generated. It also knew that your local variable `fp` was located at a -8 displacement relative to EBP so also emitted a following `F8` byte.

Comment: I am assuming that one can determine the value of the `ModR/M` byte given just the assembler instruction `call dword ptr [fp]`. As far as I can understand, that is basically what the assembler does, isn't it?. If that is correct, then, there must be a method of obtaining the `ModR/M` byte from the tables that I mentioned in my question (the CALL instruction reference and the Table 2.2, in the Intel Volumes) without having to resort to the machine code produced by the assembler.

Comment: @Alexander: No, `fp` is a symbolic constant; you have to look at an earlier line of disassembly to find out what `fp` actually means, i.e. that its `ebp-8`.  `call [fp]` doesn't uniquely determine the machine code; if `fp` had been a label on some static storage, the addressing mode would have been `[disp32]`.  The vol.2 entry for [`call`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call) itself only tells you the `reg` field for the ModRM byte, the rest comes from the text substitution of `fp` by the assembler.  (Which the disassembler is re-creating.)

Comment: @Alexander What effective address is used, and even which of the four possible opcodes (EB, FF /2, 9A, FF /3) depends on how `fp` was defined.  Note that you're not actually starting from there the example you gave in your question.  Nothing is assembling `call dword ptr [fp]`. That's what the disassembler generated by decoding the bytes `FF 55 F8` and presumably the debug information generated by the compiler that told it that `fp` was located at a -8 displacement from EBP.  If you unclick "Show symbol names" it should show `call dword ptr [ebp - 8]` instead.

Comment: @RossRidge I unclicked "Show symbol names" and the disassembled instruction came out to be `call dword ptr [ebp - 8]` as you said. Let me check to see if I'm really understanding what you're saying. Knowing that this instruction is using the data in `EBP`, one is able to identify the line labeled `[ebp+disp8]` in Table 2.2, as the one containing the ModR/M byte, which would then be found to be 55, where this line crosses the column with Reg value equal to 2. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Alexander Knowing that it's a memory operand using EBP as a base register with a displacement of -8, there are actually two different ModR/M values that could be used. the "[EBP] + disp8" value or the "[EBP] + disp32" value. The former encoding has an 8-bit (one byte) displacement, while the later has a 32-bit (four byte) displacement. The displacement of -8 can be encoded either way, but the compiler chose the "disp8" encoding because its shorter, requiring only a single byte (`F8`) to encode it. Assemblers will do the same thing.

Comment: @RossRidge Exactly. But is there any way to know a priori, the alternative used by the compiler, without taking into consideration the `ModR/M` byte printed in the disassembly?

Comment: @Alexander Why would you ignore the compiler's output when trying to determine what the compiler output?

Comment: @RossRidge Well, there may be situations where the ModeR/M byte will be hidden in the middle of  prefixes (up to 4 bytes), operating codes (up to 3 bytes),  a possible SIB byte, 1, 2, or 4 bytes or none, for displacement data, and 1, 2, or 4 bytes or none, for immediate data.

Comment: @Alexander So in other words, your real question is "How do you find the ModR/M byte in an instruction?"  The answer is that you need to decode the instruction. Start at first byte of the instruction, decode it, if the instruction is not complete then move on to the next byte and repeat. You need to take into consideration previous bytes when decoding the current byte.  If you want know more details, that's a separate question, but one that's probably too broad to be answered here.